# Can't assign a pointer to method from an inherited class

Tags: c++

I have this two class:

```
class   IBaseA
{
public:
  virtual bool  sayHello(std::string&) = 0;
  ~IBaseA(){}
};                                                                                                   

class   BaseA: public IBaseA
{
public:
  virtual bool  sayHello(std::string &str)
  {
    std::cout << "Hello " << str << std::endl;
    return (true);
  }
  BaseA(){}

};
```

Can you explain me why I'm not able to do something like that

```
bool  (IBaseA::*ptr)(std::string&) = &BaseA::sayHello;
```

> error: cannot convert 'bool (BaseA::*)(std::string&) {aka bool
>   (BaseA::*)(std::basic_string&)}' to 'bool
>   (IBaseA::*)(std::string&) {aka bool
>   (IBaseA::*)(std::basic_string&)}' in initialization

I don't understand why I can't do something like this.

But if I change the assignment to

```
bool  (IBaseA::*ptr)(std::string&) = &IBaseA::sayHello;
```

then I can use this pointer without any problems

```
BaseA A;
(A.*ptr)(str);
```

edit:
Thanks for the answers, I was thinking that since all the addresses are in the vtable, they are the same location according of what I understood from wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer-to-member conversions work opposite to normal pointer conversion. You can convert a pointer to derived class into a pointer to base class, but not vice versa. You can convert a pointer-to-member of base class to pointer-to-member of derived class, but not vice versa.

Always think whether the conversion is valid.

Plain pointers: All instances of `BaseA` are instances of `IBaseA`, so that conversion is legal. Not all `IBaseA` instances are `BaseA` instances, so you can't convert the other way.

Pointers-to-member: All members of `IBaseA` are also present in `BaseA`, so you can convert a pointer-to-member of `IBaseA` into a pointer-to-member of `BaseA`. Not all members of `BaseA` are present in `IBaseA`, however, so conversion the other way round is not possible.

Comment: Type error in last sentence: Not all members of `BaseA` are present in `IBaseA`

Answer (score 1):

Given two pointer-to-member types `T C1::*P1` and `T C2::*P2` (where T might be a function type), you can only convert P1 to P2 if C2 derives from C1. Note that this is the inverse of pointers to objects, where you can only upcast.

The reason is that if you have a pointer to a member of the base class, any subclass is guaranteed to have that member too, since it inherited it. The other way round does not apply.

This is the basic type conversion rule. It doesn't change just because that particular pointer you are taking there happens to be an override of a virtual function that exists in the base class.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is probably "because the language spec says you can't", however, think about what you are trying to do:

```
bool  (IBaseA::*ptr)(std::string&) = &BaseA::sayHello;
```

Essentially, this reads as: I want a variable called ptr which is a pointer to a member function of IBaseA, and I want it to point at the method 'sayHello' in BaseA.

Yes, the sayHello method in BaseA overrides the one in IBaseA, but they are still different methods. Imagine if you tried to use the pointer to call the method on an object of type IBaseA that *wasn't* actually a BaseA - this is syntactically allowed, but what would you expect to happen?

In other words, by taking a pointer to a member of a derived class and assigning it to a variable declared to point at a member of the base class, you would be breaking static type safety.

Answer (score 1):

While it might seem counter intuitive, you cannot convert a pointer-to-member of a derived type to a pointer-to-member to base. The correct conversion is the other way around: you can convert a pointer-to-member to base to a pointer-to-member to derived.

The reason is that the derived type is guaranteed to have that member if the base has, but the other way around it is not true (i.e. a pointer-to-member to the derived type can refer to a member that was *added* and not present in the base).

Another thing that you might be missing is that pointer-to-member functions are polymorphic, that is, you could be storing `&IBase::sayHello` and that will call `Base::sayHello` if the member to which it is applied is of type `Base`.